# Sequelize define model throws typescript error

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I recently started working on one of my older projects. I remember everything was fine before I finished on it for the last time. But now there was an typescript error.

```
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize'
import sequelizeConn from '../services/sequelize'
import { Model, InferAttributes, InferCreationAttributes } from 'sequelize'

interface EshopModelI extends Model<InferAttributes<EshopModelI>, InferCreationAttributes<EshopModelI>> {
    eshop_id: number
}

const EshopModel = sequelizeConn.define<EshopModelI>("eshop", {
    eshop_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    }
})
export default EshopModel
```

```
Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
```

But everything seems okay.
I tried copying the examples from the documentation and the same error occurs.

Versions of used packages

```
"sequelize": "^6.21.0",
"@types/node": "^17.0.43",
"nodemon": "^2.0.16",
"ts-node": "^10.8.1",
"typescript": "^4.7.3"
```

Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Comment: same here :( have you found a solution?

Comment: @Franco unfortunatelly no :(.

Comment: Problem solved with typescript 4.7.4 and sequelize 6.28.0 at least for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Sequelize utility type was updated to fix the type error that Typescript version `4.29` introduced, so you will need to upgrade your `sequelize` version to `6.25.2` or later. I can personally confirm that version `6.28.0` solves the problem (using Typescript `4.9.4`).

Here is the issue on Sequelize that documents the fix and timeline: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/15133

Here is the release that includes the fix: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/releases/tag/v6.25.2